# Name of the argument fallacy when someone only attempts to refute one of your points?

Tags: fallacies, argumentation, debate

I've never found out the name of this fallacy, or even if there is a name for it, but it seems to me it's the fallacy that occurs by far the most often. You are having a debate with someone and then you make 6 crucial points...then the other person responds by picking only point #5 and trying to refute it.

More often than not their attempt to refute the single point they singled out was invalid anyway, but as it appears as if they "hit the ball back" to you to continue the rally, they actually didn't since they ignored almost all the points made. But still since it appears that way, at least to them, it comes back to you to somehow respond.

So to be clear it looks like this:

Person A's argument:

1. argument point...
2. argument point...
3. argument point...
4. argument point...
5. argument point...
6. argument point...

And then person B responds with:

```
5. argument point...
```

That's not true because....etc

Then it's back to person A who has to do what, repeat all his points again??

In my experience it's almost always the points they ignore that are most damaging to their whole argument, and the single point they cherry picked out to refute is the weakest and more simple to refute.

Add to that the points aren't normally numbered like they are here, that's just for clarity in this example. So it's particularly difficult to respond to.

It just gives them this opportunity to say in some form or another "no, you're wrong" in response to what you said. Which is powerful in itself but seems like a fallacy to me considering the way it's achieved.

EDIT: Since many people seem to misunderstand what I mean by argument point I'll try to explain a bit more. Imagine you're reviewing a product or service and you have to make a list of pros and cons or advantage and disadvantages. So you could claim a product is not great due to the cons.

e.g.

Cons

1. very expensive
2. flimsy
3. not waterproof
4. takes too long to recharge
5. customer support rude

So my fallacy would be that someone would claim this product is in fact good and would argue against these five disadvantages by stating "no you're wrong, it's not a bad product because it actually doesn't take that long to recharge".
So regardless of whether what he said is true or not, he simply has ignored all the other cons that add up to a bad product. So even if true it's still a bad product based on the other cons.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105797/discussion-on-question-by-hasen-name-of-the-argument-fallacy-when-someone-only-a).

Comment: [Presenting too many many points in a debate is sophistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gish_gallop), people engage in a debate with a limited amount of time to spend on it. Once a friend sent me a link to "[The revelation of the pyramids"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fS9ixfQ_no) it was so full of fallacies that I got exhausted by watching it. No way I would have the time to debunk all that. So depending on the time both parties are willing to allocate to the debate, a selection of points may be brought up, and **if some arent answered, one can remind the other about it**.

Comment: Hi Hasen: The comments haven't been deleted. I had to move them to chat in line with site rules - there were +20. See link above: 'moved to chat'. Hope this helps. Best  - Geoffrey

Comment: @Geoffrey Thomas♦ Oh ok so they still exist. But still, most people coming here will not notice them since they're not visible here, so I felt necessary to point that out.

Comment: I can't reinstate comments moved to chat. Which comment answers your question?

Comment: The first response comment by Conifold stating it's 'cherry picking' with an explanation seems good. It'd be great if you could turn his comment into an actual answer. I'd accept it too.

Comment: Conifold: The OP asked me to reinstate your comment on the display page because he considered it the aptest response to his question. He asks me (see comment above) to convert it into an answer but plainly I cannot do this. I can only draw the point to your attention. Best - Geoffrey.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't described this issue clearly.

In general, if A makes ten arguments for a position and B refute one of the arguments there are multiple reasons why B might do that. B might think that if he refutes one argument your position is refuted, which would be wrong. B might think he wants to take your arguments out one at a time so he starts with one argument with the aim of getting agreement that it's wrong before he moves on to the others. Or he might just want to refute that particular argument without having any intention to go on to any further arguments.

Another problem is that looking for the name of a fallacy to use in an argument is a bad idea in many cases. A name just means you've put a label on something not that you understand it.

Comment: I thought I made it clear that the person was ignoring the points because he couldn't refute them? Even if he did think if he somehow just refuted one argument it was enough, he'd have to specifically state "therefore all your other points make no sense" otherwise he's just not addressing those other points...

Comment: Your point last doesn't seem to make much sense, clearly I understand what the situation is, I just wondered if there is a name for it. There is a strength in named fallacies that are recognised so quoting them is powerful in an argument. Logically it shouldn't be that way, but that's just how humans respond.

Comment: Oh and they never, ever go back to the points they initally ignored....ever...not unless you bring them up again and again and they normally try to ignore them even on subsequent times.

Comment: Without seeing the actual argument I can't tell who is in the wrong. It is extremely common for people to make points that fail basic tests of logic and then fancy that they have pwned the person they're arguing with.

Comment: If you think you've pwned the person who's made points that fail basic tests of logic then you need to SAY THAT IN YOUR ARGUMENT RESPONSE...just saying nothing is making yourself pwned by your opponent...it actually reminds me of another idiotic fallacy people use like "do you realise what you said doesn't make any sense?" Then no explanation, just that single sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The specifics rely on a concrete example of that, but there's a good chance that it's not a fallacy at all.

Like ideally your arguments and premises would lead up to a conclusion so it would be:

> (A,B,C,D,E) -> Conclusion

or idk:

> (A,B) -> C, (C,D) -> E and (E,F) -> Conclusion

or something like that. So pointing out that any of these premises or (pre-)conclusions is false or invalid would have a destructive effect on the soundness or respectively the validity of your entire argument.

That does not mean that you're conclusion must be false, but it means that your implication is false and that indeed puts the ball is back in your field to either fix that problem or to give up on this claim.

But it seems that you think about something more along the lines of:

> 1. (A,B) -> C
> 2. (D,E) -> C
> 3. (F,G) -> C

> ...

So each of the arguments is it's own implication independent of the others. So showing that one of them is not sound or even invalid only works for that one argument and as said not in and of itself debunks the conclusion. Yet it still puts the ball back in your field to either fix or give up that specific argument, so at least in that regard it's still not a fallacy.

Also depending on the medium of communication it's usually not ideal to produce multiple arguments at the same time. Like if it's a write-up of all counter arguments then it might be ok, but in a discussion that's more akin to attempting a DOS attack ("denial of service" due to a flooding with requests) on the opponent, so rhetoric rather than substance.

And then you approach, not so much logical, but a practical problem. Like if someone comes at you with a list of 10 arguments and each of them crumbles away under scrutiny without resistances or attempts to back it up, then you're kinda approaching the point where you ask yourself whether that's a good use of your lifetime, because the other end seems to be dead set on a conclusion and seems to take up any argument in it's defense rather than having found the conclusion as a necessary result of a set of premises. So no matter how many arguments you're taking down, the other end will always come up with another one and no a plurality of arguments in favor of something means very little in it's defense. So they're acting in bad faith and leaving the scene unless they are willing to defend their claims is unfortunately often the best option you've got.

That in itself is acting fallacious, because "the boy who cried wolf", may now have actually seen a wolf and can be employed by bad faith actors as a means to shut down an argument without engaging with the meat of it, but it could also be a useful heuristic when engaging with bad faith actors. So it's a double edged sword that is logically problematic. So you kinda rely on an educated audience to distinguish one from the other. Which is again not a logical problem but a practical one.

So to mitigate that you could just focus on your strongest argument instead.

If they then again pick a part of it that is not relevant for the argument or which side tracks ignoring the argument, then it's idk a strawman fallacy or something like that, where you don't fight the argument, but a mock version of it. Or again they could have a real point if your argument actually relies on that point. Then it would be again up to you to confirm that the argument is debunked, how it could be saved or how the integral part of it is still untouched and valid.

So it pretty much depends on an actual example of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is one person trying to prove that a statement is correct, and one person trying to prove that you have no evidence.

You have five arguments that purport to prove your statement. The other person shows that one of your arguments is not just unproven but wrong. So the situation is changed: Instead of five statements that may or may not be correct or wrong, you have four that may or may not be correct or wrong, and one that is most definitely wrong.

That very much weakens your position. Not only has the other person shown one of your arguments to be wrong. They have also shown that you are careless in making arguments, therefore your arguments 1 to 4 need much more scrutiny before they can be accepted, and you should provide much more evidence that your arguments 1 to 4 are correct.

It's a fallacy to thing that disproving your statement is the only result that would count. Instead, the other person has created very reasonable doubt in your arguments. It's like being in court and making five statements. If the defense proves that one statement was a lie, then your reliability as a witness is very much in doubt.

Comment: ???? That doesn't make even the slightest bit of sense. He shows ONE argument is wrong or unproven so four of the arguments are wrong???? So if I shoot one person of five then the other four also die....?? I think you must have made a mistake writing your answer or something, please check it again.

Comment: No but if you're charged with the murder of 5 people and the court can prove that you shot at least one of them then you're already getting convicted even if there are still 4 open cases, because you've already been proven to be a murderer. Or in that case a person being careless with their arguments.

Comment: @haxor789 That's a strawman argument, my statement was whether they die or not, not whether anyone gets convicted for it. Your example is also bad because it just highlights the limitations of the law. You get the same conviction if you murder everyone on earth as you do if you just murder one person, it doesn't mean your conviction in any way included all those people... A better example would be someone selling five items and you pay for one and argue that you paid for all of them because you paid for one...

Comment: @Hasen No my point was exactly this idea of "fool me once shame on you fool me twice shame on me". Of course that is an ad hominem fallacy as it disproves the credibility of the messenger not the message. But it's also a practical heuristic when dealing with bad faith actors. No accusation implied, but you haven't given a good example for your case.

Comment: @haxor789 You've given a strawman argument which is about as bad an example as can be. The statement that 'affecting one thing out of 5 would automatically affect the others' is currently a random statement with zero proof. There's no logical reason why it would, there has to be a link made between the single thing and the four other things, we can't just assume it's true. That has not been done. 5 people on trial for murder, one gets convicted, it doesn't affect the others. Fooling that person once also doesn't seem to apply here. There's no link made so as it is the statement is super weak.

Answer (score 0):

For me this looks like a [Argument from fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_fallacy) (or called "fallacy fallacy"):

> It has the general argument form:
> If P, then Q.
> P is a fallacious argument.
> Therefore, Q is false.

> Thus, it is a special case of denying the antecedent where the antecedent, rather than being a proposition that is false, is an entire argument that is fallacious. A fallacious argument, just as with a false antecedent, can still have a consequent that happens to be true. The fallacy is in concluding the consequent of a fallacious argument has to be false.

> That the argument is fallacious only means that the argument cannot succeed in proving its consequent. But showing how one argument in a complex thesis is fallaciously reasoned does not necessarily invalidate its conclusion if that conclusion is not dependent on the fallacy.

Here's a similar example:

> Tom: I speak English. Therefore, I am English.

> Ben: Americans and Canadians, among others, speak English too. By assuming that speaking English and being English always go together, you have just committed the package-deal fallacy. You are incorrect. Therefore, you are not English.

> The fact that Tom's argument was fallacious is not, in itself, a proof that his conclusion is false.

Btw, according to principle of sufficient reason, ideally there's one and only one reason (argument) to explain a concluding effect. You may need to structure all your arguments into a united one as a classical syllogistic form like above example from the reference...

Comment: That doesn't seem the same as my example. It was about listing multiple points where only one single point was 'cherry picked' by the opposing party and refuted. In your example 'Tom' only gives one single point anyway so does not appear to be the same thing as I was describing.

Comment: @Hasen That's why in my last para I hinted real valid argument format should be syllogistic logical form. There's only one real (however complex and combinatorial) condition to sufficiently cause a conclusion per PSR, as manifested in sciences inductive laws and math deductive theorems. In practice most people are not sure which is the real cause, so they need to list multiple independent arguments trying to cover the real one which is itself a red herring irrelevance fallacy... You multiple arguments are merely necessary conditions at best...

Comment: @Hasen You either bundle all your multiple arguments as a whole sufficient reason, and in this case if one of it is refuted, it doesn't mean your conclusion is wrong, otherwise your opponent commits *fallacy fallacy* as shown in my answer above; or your multiple arguments as a whole merely indicates some necessary conditions, in this case it doesn't matter if any of them is refuted, since your argument is only necessary not sufficient, the formal fallacy is on your side...

Comment: You can't just bundle arguments into one since most of the time it's impossible. The most vital part of my question is that it's numerical. It's about MULTIPLE points and someone choosing only one of them - kind of similar to the game of roulette. If you're not addressing that then you're talking about something else entirely. Your example of listing several points because they're not sure of the real cause only talks about a unique situation, in the real world, people, countries, ideas etc can and do all have multiple problems.

Comment: Your example is particularly awful. Tom could easily make multiple points to prove his argument. e.g. I speak English. Therefore, I am English. I was also born in England and my parents were born in England. Easy for him to make multiple points. Then his opposition could simply say exactly what Ben said above, cherry picking ONLY the part about speaking English and not addressing his other points that he was born in England and his parents were born in England too.....to be honest I really think you didn't understand my original question at all...

Comment: @Hasen misunderstanding is everywhere and that's why we love wisdom to arrive at rare truth which most people don't care much... First of all your 6 multiple arguments should really be organized to prove or solve 6 different questions, like here at PSE we only expect one question at a time. Of course I understand in reality most often all those 6 points may be inter-related to serve for a common question. If this is the case, you need to first organize the 6 points logical causality/relation. It's like math, one theorem only proves one point though its premises may be several but organized...

Comment: @Hasen Again use math as the ultimate logical role model, some hard problem may need several theorems, lemmas, and propositions to be organized in a clear chain of sufficient reasons (per Leibniz's PSR necessarily in all possible worlds using modal logic jargon) to arrive at your final key destination. To prove you are English, it doesn't really matter you speak English, it's not the sufficient reason. In common sense, it has only to do with your nationality, so this is the point, you just need to show this sufficient reason. All other points may be correlated, but not true reason here...

Comment: Your comments are getting weirder and weirder. Someone can make any argument they want, it's up their opposing party to refute those. You may as well say ad hominem doesn't exist because no-one should ever use it....unfortunately people do and very often too. Someone may very well make those three different argument points to prove that they are English and their opposition may only refute only one of them. That's why we have logical fallacies in the first place...

Comment: Another example because I really don't think you're getting it. Person A: It will take too much time and also be too expensive. Person B: It won't be too expensive because of so and so...He only addresses one of the two points.

Comment: @Hasen I fully understand you're talking about folk talk rather than normative logical talk and I'm fully aware most folk talks are full of fallacies on both sides like ur above example. Say boss A doesn't want to start a project while person B wants. Boss A thinks she has 2 arguments for her conclusion (doesn't want to start the project), and B refutes 2nd argument. B certainly has above "fallacy fallacy" that even B is right doesn't mean A's conclusion is wrong. But A also has logical fallacy since either A's 2 arguments cannot lead to A's conclusion OR A's 2nd premise is truly wrong...

Comment: Yes I'm talking about any argument between two human beings. Any argument can and most often WILL have multiple points, whether it's two people having a heated televised political discussion, or two people arguing about the price of fish. Like in the example above, you can't roll 'time' and 'expense' into one point - you can put it in one single sentence....but still it's MULTIPLE points, so your opposition can choose just one of those points and try to refute that alone. That is the logical fallacy we're talking about in this question.

Comment: @Hasen this is one of the reasons I'll shun such talks... using math logic as a role model, if a plane figure is a triangle (point 1) + it has a right angle (point 2), then we have Pythagorean Theorem (a^2+b^2=c^2) as its conclusion. If any of the 2 points is refuted, then the conclusion *may* not hold and its logic fallacy is formal. But in folk talk, unless you have specific domain scientific induction law level knowledge, usually the multiple points of an argument is to *persuade* others. If "takes too much time" is "really" a showstopper, expense is moot. The burden is to show "really"...

Comment: You've already proven your theory incorrect with your own example. Argument: 1. I speak English therefore I'm English. 2. My parents are English therefore I'm English. 3. I was born in England therefore I'm English. Your opposition replies: "Americans and Canadians, speak English too, therefore speaking English does not prove you are English."  According to your logic the 'triangle has now folded' in this argument...Also nobody has mentioned maths. Just because there is a numerical value doesn't mean it's all about maths.

Comment: If you open the chat comments above you'll see the correct answer as the first response  by user Conifold. Maybe you'll understand it all better if you read that.

Comment: @Hasen I've read the comment now, cherry pick as offered could be a suitable umbrella name covering many cases such as fallacy of anecdotal evidence, false dichotomy, confirmation bias, etc (from wikipedia). It's mostly used in statistical inductive inference cases. But your case of multiple points are not independent samples, they somehow work together to convince or prove a final conclusion. That's why Conifold also suggested to make one, the "most damaging" argument point which is inline with what I hinted. If u're a Platonist, u'll have faith to reduce language to math logical form.

Comment: @Hasen I understand ur debate frustration since ur opponent just try to attack one of ur points and maybe (s)he's weak to actually rebute that point, just try to kick the ball back to u for them to have a rest. That's the chance for u to show to all that every point of your arguments are true. Of course outside science fields, truth may be hard to agree upon, that's why u need to learn rethoric in addition to logic/philosophy which Aristotle emphasized as same with all the ancient sophists as their main genuine skill... Philosopher always has some Platonic blood and demand reduced to logic.

Comment: @Hasen final suggestion if u're still not satisfied or gained much from philosophical discussions (sadly philosophy is about truth and logos/logic, not how to convince others rhetorically). The original love+sophistry had been changed to love+wisdom long ago as the official explanation of the word "philosophy". In ancient Greece, rhetoric was emphasized, but later most true philosophers were mostly like monks uninterested in fame or money, power, so despise rhetoric in general. Maybe u can go to other site like English to ask debate techniques...

Comment: Sorry but you can't put it's expensive AND takes too much time into one point. You can try limit your points but it's not always possible. Also there's too much focus on what's wrong with the initial speaker when this is about the fallacy of the responder. Both or neither can be at fault, I simply wanted to know the name of the fault. You can make points one at a time to force them to respond but ultimately it's still incorrect of them to cherry pick one.

Comment: Your whole argument is a guy punched you, because you made him angry, so you shouldn't make him angry, but you're missing completely that it's also incorrect for him to punch you. Pretty much anything and everything has multiple problems, thus multiple points. If you only pick one then your video game only gets one bug fixed.

Comment: Nobody said too much time is a showstopper. Many things have problems that make them difficult, they don't have to individually be showstoppers. Often multiple points/problems add up to a show stopper.  You never heard the phrase "the straw that broke the camel's back"? I think you're viewing the world with rose tinted glasses.

Comment: @Hasen I understand what u described and the subtlety in common life situations outside exact science and math realms. I just want to emphasize cherry pick fallacy is more fit to describe induction (bias) fallacy when cherry picking only those samples within ur bias while ignoring other non-conforming samples. But ur case I still think it's better named as my "fallacy fallacy"(bad reasons fallacy), meaning even ur argument as a whole does not hold (even due to only one point), it doesn't mean your conclusion is wrong. It only means your logic is not entirely correct. If I'm ur opponent....

Comment: @Hasen ...I'll also do similar probably, to refute your seeming weakest argument point out of your rhetoric many points. Nothing wrong with it that's why u seem to feel this kind of "fallacy" is everywhere... To try to convince others using rhetoric, besides employing multiple points, I'll use good and powerful (emotional) metaphors or allegories such as those in religious boos, like Buddhism's Parable of the Poisoned Arrow to express your position with metaphoric argument (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Poisoned_Arrow)

Comment: I think I'll have to give up trying to explain it to you. The irony is that your own argument against me here even contains multiple points but you have failed to notice that. You've also used the fallacy itself by failing to address most of my points. e.g. Me: 'Expensive' and 'too much time' are multiple points, you: if too much time is a showstopper it should be only one point. Me: it doesn't have to be a showstopper, multiple points add up to be a showstopper - ie 'the straw that broke the camel's back'. you: no response to this point.

Comment: A "fallacy fallacy" is not specific to anything. It's like asking what type of problem is this and you say it's a 'problem'...it's not an answer. Like I said, Conifold already had it correct and so did several in the comments in the chat. He advises giving only one point to avoid this but that's obviously not always possible.It's like saying everything in the world only has one problem. Often it's 10 problems that add up to a showstopper, while with just one or a few problems and the show can go on.

Comment: @Hasen philosophical dialectic discussion should never feel boring or complete, u should enjoy... Per ur concerns above, that's why I emphasized before we need domain logic/model to organize all you points to your utility goal. The burden is on you to model time+money cause showstopper as when a straw falls. A weighted linear sum model is common but may be naive. That's why math modeling is more useful than rhetoric, u can show your math model to *convince* others why current situation is a showstopper. Of course your model needs reasonable since most life problems are not scientific problem..

Comment: @Hasen once u employ a math modeling to logically organize your multiple argument points, then when anyone attacks either of those points, you just say, hooray let's calculate the result to verify it's a showstopper or not if you says spending $2,000 for 2 weeks by a contractor is not expensive, let's substitute 2000, 2 weeks into my model... This is called verification principle of modern famous logical positivism movement in western analytic philosophy to get rid of all those meaningless metaphysical arguments for thousands of years...

Comment: @Hasen as long as there's no model based on known valid scientific laws there won't be any exact moment "'the straw that broke the camel's back", though sometimes it maybe seem emotional toll if u lose a major argument during a debate. That's why a good analogy helps much in rhetoric, even scientist and mathematician use metaphors a lot to help guess their theorems/laws. Cantor proposed his famous continuum hypothesis CH solely based on some analogy btw Q->R and ordinal extensions, but it turns out CH cannot be proved by current math ZFC foundations and most pros like Cohen believes it's false

Comment: @Hasen True causality is truth knowledge which is hard to arrive at if not standing on other giants' shoulders. True causality is different from mundane arguments of multiple points we often engaged. The famous Greek atomist philosopher Democritus used to say he prefers to discover a causality rather than become a king of Persia... (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democritus)